# Symfony / Doctrine "refers to the owning side field which does not exist" - but property is present in class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

SeUserProgress and SeUser.  The SeUserProgress table holds multiple entries per user.  This is expressed via the two following mappings.

**class: SeUserProgress**

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SeUser", inversedBy="progress")
* @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer", nullable=true)
*/ 
private $user;
```

**class: SeUser**

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SeUserProgress", mappedBy="user")
*/ 
private $progress;
```

However I keep getting an error message saying

```
The association PROJECT\ThisBundle\Entity\SeUser#progress refers to the owning side  field PROJECT\ThisBundle\Entity\SeUserProgress#user which is not defined as association.

The association PROJECT\ThisBundle\Entity\SeUser#progress refers to the owning side  field PROJECT\ThisBundle\Entity\SeUserProgress#user which does not exist.
```

I can even call the progress property via the code below( though it returns all progress for all users ).

```
$user->getProgress()
```

Any suggestions as to why Doctrine is not recognising the mapped property would be appreciated.

Comment: Be careful with your naming of variables. Since you use a OneToMany relationship, either one of your variables must be plural. In this case it would be `$progresses`. This will help you later to understand and read your code. To your question: Did you `use `-include your classes properly or are they in the same namespace. That could cause such errors.

Comment: Hi Benny thanks for the information. The classes are in the same namespace, and work with other entities.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change your code from @ORM\Column to @ORM\JoinColumn:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SeUser", inversedBy="progress")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */ 
private $user;
```